# getmaxyx always returns 1 and 1 in pdcurses instead of the number of rows and columns

Tags: c, curses, pdcurses

```
#include <curses.h>

int main() {
    initscr();
    int row, col;
    getmaxyx(stdscr, row, col);
    printw("%d %d", row, col);
    getch();
}
```

If I compile this code with ncurses (`gcc -lncurses test.c`), I get, as expected, the number of rows and columns of the terminal (31 and 88 in my case), but if I compile it with pdcurses (`gcc -lpdcurses -lSDL test.c`) I get 1 and 1 as the output. Why is that? Am I missing something? Resizing the terminal with `resize_term(100, 100);` does not change the output

Comment: What are `a` and `b`? Where do you set `row` and `col`?

Comment: oops sorry, `a` should be `row` and `b` should be `col`

Comment: You may want: `getmaxyx(stdscr, &row, &col);` to obtain the values. Otherwise row/col is uninitialized

Comment: No, `getmaxyx` is a macro and the `&` should not be used (https://linux.die.net/man/3/getmaxyx)

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons pdcurses doesn't like ncurses `curses.h`, changing the header to `xcurses/curses.h` solves the issue for me

Comment: Don't change the header specified in the source code -- change the compiler's search path: gcc -I/usr/include/xcurses (or wherever) etc.